# SQL Server Concurrency Issue

Tags: sql-server, concurrency

We have a SQL server concurrency issue we are facing and would like some ideas on how to solve it. There are several procedures we have written the contain `INSERT/UPDATE` statements on tables in a Set based manner. I will try to illustrate an example here

Lets assume that the isolation level set by the AppServer over the JDBC connection is `READ COMMITTED`

```
DELETE FROM TargetAmountTable
/*whole bunch of JOINS on other tables*/
WHERE SourceAmountSetTable.isModified = 1

INSERT INTO TargetAmountSetTable
SELECT /**whole bunch of JOINS**/
WHERE SourceAmountSetTable.isModified = 1

UPDATE TargetAmountSetTable
SET TargetAmountSetTable.isModified = 1
/*whole bunch of JOINS*/
WHERE SourceAmountSetTable.isModified = 1

INSERT INTO TargetAmountTable
SELECT /*whole bunch of JOINS*/
WHERE SourceAmountSetTable.isModified = 1

UPDATE SourceAmountSetTable
SET SourceAmountSetTable.isModified = 0
FROM /*whole bunch of JOINS*/
WHERE SourceAmountSetTable.isModified = 1
```

So the problem we are facing is, when there are multiple processes trying to do the `INSERT` on the [TargetAmountTable], duplicate rows are added since the last `UPDATE` statement is not yet executed

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: With a transaction? And I'm not sure I follow your simplified example, but you could consider DELETE ... OUTPUT INTO.

Comment: Maybe different processes shouldn't be working with the same `isModified = 1` subset. Maybe you could create a SQL Server Agent job that would do all this at regular intervals. Or maybe you could take a different approach altogether instead of using `isModified`. Knowing what the "whole bunch of JOINS" are might help. Or it might be completely irrelevant, but you could start with a short explanation of what these five statements are doing, in essence.

Comment: Would an applock help you? http://sqlblog.com/blogs/louis_davidson/archive/2007/05/07/using-application-locks-to-implement-a-critical-section-in-t-sql-code.aspx

Comment: It sounds to me like you're trying to have multiple threads 'process' the same source data, this is solvable by creating a thread assignment/ownership pattern.  But like the other comments more clarification is required.

Answer (score 1):

In general what you want here is an explicit transaction around your code.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
... your code ....
COMMIT
```

However there are down sides to concurrency here as well.  While your transaction is open any locks needed to perform the tasks will be held until the end of the transaction.  That means that the next set of code that needs to run will have to wait until this one is completed.

Even worse you increase your odds of creating a deadlock.  A deadlock would occur when session 1 is holding a set of locks X.  Session 2 is holding a set of locks Y then needs to get a hold of some of the resources held by X.  If session 1 then needs resources in Y you get into a situation where neither session can ever complete.  This causes a deadlock and one of the sessions will be rolled back.

The solution to this is to make sure that your transactions take as little time as possible.  What worries me is the `whole bunch of JOINs` comments.  That tends to mean the commands will take a fair amount of time increasing your odds of blocking and deadlocking.  If I'm wrong and the whole piece of code is fast then you shouldn't have major issues (there is always a chance of deadlocking, speed just reduces it).

Because your example is so simplified it's going to be hard to go beyond such a general piece of advice.  If you'd like to post a better idea of the actual code we might be able to help you in other ways.

Additional information on [blocking & deadlocking here](http://sqlstudies.com/2015/07/01/blocking-and-deadlocking-on-purpose/).

Answer (score 0):

A transaction like Kenneth Fisher answered

And look at optimizing
Why are you updating after the insert?
Why not just insert a hard coded TargetAmountSetTable.isModified of 1 in the insert?

Another option is to output the whole lot of joins once to a #processTable